# Get all the whitespace except new lines from the start of a line until any content?

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to get all the white space leading up to any content on a line. I'm not getting the results with my RegExp:

```
var oneLineOfText = "           Hello World";
var whiteSpace = oneLineOfText.replace(/([\t| ]*).*$/, "$1");
```

Expected results (inside of quotes):

```
"           "
```

NB: In the expected results it looks like the tab characters are getting converted to space characters.

Note: I do not want to match new lines. I'm trying to get the indentation amount from the string. If there is a new line or a few new lines then I'm going to assume no indentation.

Comment: What exact output do you need? Show an example string input and expected output. Try `var whiteSpace = oneLineOfText.replace(/^(\s+)[\s\S]*$/, "$1");`.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with multiple languages?

Comment: Because JavaScript and ActionScript are siblings. They are both ECMAScript. If a RegEx works in one language it will work in the other (for the most part). So if you are a JS or AS developer you can answer it.

Comment: AS has a bit extended regex grammar (it [is said](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) to support `/s` and `/x` modifiers that are not supported by JS regex engine). BTW, [your regex works for the current example](https://regex101.com/r/xM0yG0/1).

Comment: That site is amazing. I forgot about those extra flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[ \t]*
```

- `^` - from the beginning of the line
- `[ \t]*` - as many spaces or tabs as possible

---

```
var oneLineOfText = "           Hello World";
var whiteSpace    = oneLineOfText.match(/^[ \t]*/)[0];
whiteSpace.length // => 11
```

---

If you want to match a multiline string you will have to add appropriate `gm` modifiers:

```
var multilineText = "   foo\n     bar";
var whiteSpaces   = multilineText.match(/^[ \t]*/gm);
whiteSpaces[0].length // => 3
whiteSpaces[1].length // => 5
```

Comment: That  would be correct. But I forgot to mention that I don't want new lines. I'll update the question.

Comment: What happens if there is no match in the first example? `oneLine.match()[0]` will throw an error.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts, this was the code to show that the regex is working, not the code that you should use. Obviously you have to handle that in your logic.